¿Como mantengo el texto del textfield luego de un setState? - Flutter
Tengo mi clase con un Textfield y un DropdownMenu, al Textfield le asigno un controlador con un Texto que proviene de una lista que recibo de otra clase, no hay problema editando el texto, pero cuando cambio la opción en el DropdownMenu se lanza el setState y el texto editado vuelve a ser el texto de inicio, Aquí está el código.
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget{
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

List<String> categoria = ['A',' B', 'C', 'D'];

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<String> list = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as List<String>;
    TextEditingController controlador = TextEditingController(text: list.first);
    String currentValue = categoria.first;
    String tempValue = '';

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar( title: const Text('Testing'), ),
        body: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            TextField(
              controller: controlador,
              onChanged: (value) {
                tempValue = value;
              },
            ),
            
            DropdownMenu(
              width: 90,
              initialSelection: currentValue,
              onSelected: (String? newValue){
                setState(() {
                  currentValue = newValue!;
                  controlador.text = tempValue;
                });
              },
              dropdownMenuEntries: categoria.map<DropdownMenuEntry<String>>((String value){
                return DropdownMenuEntry(
                  value: value,
                  label: value,
                );
              }).toList(),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Intenté inicializar el controller fuera del Build mediante iniState() pero así no podría colocarle un valor de la lista que tome de otra clase.

saca tus variables: tempValue y controlador (algo asi) quedando por fuera de tu build, asi evitas que se sobreescriba
String tempValue = '';
TextEditingController controlador = TextEditingController(text: 
list.first);
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {


Me marca error, no puedo acceder a la lista porque esta dentro del build

entonces saca tu lista igual como te mostre anteriormente

La lista requiere del context a la hora de buildear el widget
